# Mobile automation with javascript using webdriver io

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest me how to scroll down using webdriverio(4) Javascript for mobile app. This is a android app, need to scroll to the bottom of the page. Any suggestions will be really helpful.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should look it up in the documentation / API for webdriver.io V4 (which is actually not on their main page since wdio V6 is latest version).
It is here: http://v4.webdriver.io/api.html

And there you can find all the methods needed to perform actions you want to.
In this particular case you should look for "swipe" methods.
(there are other methods that could work similar like swipe but be aware of deprecation warnings, there are quite a few of them in there and also make sure you're using methods for mobile apps).

You can try "swipe" method: http://v4.webdriver.io/api/mobile/swipe.html
which looks like this:

```
browser.swipe([selector][,xoffset][,yoffset][,speed]);
```

and it doesn't require selector to be used, so you can skip it and just swipe down.
There is also "swipeDown" method but this one requires you to provide selector for the element you want to swipe from / on: http://v4.webdriver.io/api/mobile/swipeDown.html

And it looks like this:

```
browser.swipeDown(selector[,yoffset],speed);
```

Anyway...
If you're just starting to write your tests maybe consider switching to latest webdriverIO 6 and using some of the great boilerplate projects provided there:
https://webdriver.io/docs/boilerplate.html

For example this project: https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/
contains great documentation on how it works, example tests for both android and iOS apps and mobile browser tests too. There's also FAQ for people learning with this project.